# Refactoring code - variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, code-duplication

I have 3 buttons that concatenate input text differently:

```
 var myTxtArea = document.getElementById('KWarea');
 myTxtArea.value = myTxtArea.value.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');
 var lines = $('#KWarea').val().replace(/\*/g, '').split('\n');
 $('#produce').click(function () {
     var endString = "";

     myTxtArea.value = myTxtArea.value.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '');
     var lines = $('#KWarea').val().replace(/\*/g, '').split('\n');
     for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
         endString += '"*' + $.trim(lines[i]) + '*"' + ',' + '"* ' + lines[i] + ' *"' + ',';
         //   console.log(lines[i]);
     }
     var trimmedStr = endString.slice(0, -1);
     $('#result1').html("ctx.keywords MATCHES (" + trimmedStr + ")");
     $('#Strlength').html('Total string length: ' + trimmedStr.length);

 });

 $('#produce2').click(function () {
     var endString = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
         endString += '"*' + $.trim(lines[i]) + '*"' + ',';
     }
     var trimmedStr = endString.slice(0, -1);
     $('#result1').html("ctx.keywords MATCHES (" + trimmedStr + ")");
     $('#Strlength').html('Total string length: ' + trimmedStr.length);

 });

 $('#produce3').click(function () {
     var endString = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
         endString += '"' + $.trim(lines[i]) + '"' + ',';
     }
     var trimmedStr = endString.slice(0, -1);
     $('#result1').html("ctx.keywords MATCHES (" + trimmedStr + ")");
     $('#Strlength').html('Total string length: ' + trimmedStr.length);

 });
```

I would like to avoid repeating over and over the following:

```
  $('#result1').html("ctx.keywords MATCHES (" + trimmedStr + ")");
     $('#Strlength').html('Total string length: ' + trimmedStr.length);
```

But `trimmedStr` depends on `endString` and I can't refactor without ending up with some `var undefined`

[Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyka88/g8rsxmy3/2/)

Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply create a separated function for those 2 lines?

Comment: If this is working code that you want suggestions for improving, that's what http://codereview.stackexchange.com is for.

Comment: function name(){ /* that code */ } and calling name() within .click() does not work -> var undefined. If Im doing something wrong, please edit my fiddle :)

Comment: Thanks, never knew it exists (though I see it's quite new).

Comment: @jfriend00 This sounds like a specific programming problem (while the code works, there is a specific goal of how to improve it), I don't think this is off-topic for Stack Overflow. (If you want to have a longer discussion about this, welcome to chat in [The 2nd Monitor - Code Review Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor))

Comment: @AndreyDoronin: Use a parameter for that function where you pass the string

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - nowhere in my comment did I say this was off-topic for StackOverflow (so please don't make up things I didn't say).  I suggested they could get help in codereview if they want which seems like a perfectly valid comment as this code could be improved in a bunch of ways beyond only what the OP was asking about.

Comment: @jfriend00 Nowhere in my comment did I explicitly say that you said you thought this was off-topic for Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - geez. Seriously?  Are you just trying to argue no particular point for the purposes or arguing?  Remind me to stay away from codereview or ever recommending it.  All, I ever get there is grief.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, all I wanted to do was to prevent *someone else* from voting to close and commenting with "I'm voting to close this question because it belongs at Code Review". I did not mean anything bad. This question *could* be a nice CR question, but that's a whole different story.

Comment: I was working on a revision of your code, but I came across an inconsistency I don't understand.  You create a global called `lines` that two of your click handlers use, but the other click handlers creates it's own local variable by the same name.  Is this really what you intend or is one of those a mistake?

Comment: Yes, that's a mistake, just forgot to take it out of the 3rd .click. thank you for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a little bigger refactoring might be beneficial. Something along these lines?

```
function getInput () {
    var lines = $('#KWarea').val().split('\n');
    var plainKeywords = lines.map(function (line) {
        // Match the line for correct input string
        return line.match(/^\s*\**([a-z 0-9]+)\**\s*$/i)[1];  
    }).filter(function (word) {
        // No match -> discard line
        return word !== undefined;
    });
    return plainKeywords;
}

function getKeywords (type, word) {
    if(type == 1) return ['"*' + word + '*"', '"* ' + word + ' *"'];
    if(type == 2) return ['"*' + word + '*"'];
    return ['"' + word + '"'];
}

function showKeywords (type) {
    // Comma seperated list of keywords
    var output = getInput().reduce(function (memo, i) {
        return memo.concat(getKeywords(type, i));
    }, []).join(',');
    $('#result1').html('ctx.keywords MATCHES (' + output + ')');
    $('#Strlength').html('Total string length: ' + output.length);
}

 $('#produce').click(showKeywords.bind(null, 1));
 $('#produce2').click(showKeywords.bind(null, 2));
 $('#produce3').click(showKeywords.bind(null, 3));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8rsxmy3/5/

Comment: Thank you, it is this kind of code review that helps me become better at coding.